# Tibco JMS Queue Requestor" or "JMS Queue Sender" Dinamic JMS properties mapping

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I am working with Tibco BW5.I have JMS selectors string that looks like this:

```
SelectorString = "Name='Value' AND Name='Value' AND Name='Value' AND ...."
```

I need to use this string in "JMS Queue Requestor" or "JMS Queue Sender" as JMS selectors.

**Solution:**

For setting selectors to "JMS Queue Requestor" or "JMS Queue Sender" I am using "DynamicProperties" in "Input" tab:

[image: dynamic selectors]

For mapping SelectorString to "DynamicProperties" I created  "Repeat-Until-True" group with MapData inside.

Repeat condition:

```
($i >= count(tib:tokenize($Start/root/SelectorString, "AND")))
```

[image: Repeat]

I map "name" to:

```
tib:trim(tib:tokenize(tib:tokenize($Start/root/SelectorString, "AND")[$i], "=")[1])
```

I map "value" to:

```
substring-before(substring-after(tib:tokenize(tib:tokenize($Start/root/SelectorString, "AND")[$i], "=")[2], "'"), "'")
```

Then I set accumulated output to "JMS Queue Requestor" dynamic properties.

Please see screenshot:

[image: Please see attached screenshot]

Is there more elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not much experience with set-based math ... a typical "sequential programmer's approach to sets":-(

Assuming that the you have a non-hierarchical statement (containing ONLY "AND" between name value pairs) you can once translate " AND " into a single "special char" (like "¶"), use a for-each XML element with the tokenized string it by this char and then split and trim the name and values inside the for-each.

[Process with mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb3Ip.png)

[ActivityInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNTSz.png):

That's the set-based approach which btw is much faster than the iteration loop (4 simple lines of XPath code)